# .htaccess to load specific index file when url not exist

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

I am updating urls of a project and have this old url:
http://www.example.com/phones/index.php

This folder phones doesnt exists anymore but I want to catch the old traffic and when someone visits this url I want .htaccess file to load file store.php which is located in the root directory
How can I do this with htaccess file so the url in the address bar to stay 
http://www.example.com/phones/index.php but to load store.php file, Thank you in advance !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1 !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/index\.php$ store.php [L,NC]
```

Comment: Anubhava, thank you for helping me. What if phones in url is variable part? How will htaccess direcive will look like? I dont what to make thousands rows with rules in the htaccess file? thanks

Comment: ok I edited the answer to take care of that but it is better to specify this in question to get good answer at first go.

Comment: You are right man, sorry for not specifying this in the question. Your code works, but I can accept it in 4 min. Thank you so much !

Comment: anubhava, how will htaccess look like if I have 2 variable folders in the url like: http://www.example.com/phones/nokia/ to load again store.php file which is in the root? thanks

Comment: Then replace `RewriteRule` line above with `RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ store.php [L,NC]`

Comment: Anubhava, may I please you to look at this question please:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37609306/htaccess-to-load-index-in-dynamic-folder-name
I know you are .htaccess master :)

Answer (score 0):

In **.htaccess** of your root directory.

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [L]
```