# .htaccess to load index in dynamic folder name

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I am having problem with .htaccess to load index in dynamic folder name.
Here is my directory structure:

```
root/products/ -> this is constant folder name
```

instead of using GET for product urls:

```
root/products/index.php?product=my-product-url
```

I want to put the product url after products folder and to look like:

```
root/products/my-product-url
```

My .htaccess file is in products folder and has this code:

```
RewriteBase /products/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L,NC]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

but it doesn't work.
It actually loads the index file but in the console I can see it is looding js file over 1000 times if I don't stop the page.. It looks like is reloading the page so many times and adds I suppose timestamp at the end of the js file like:

GET http://www.mysiteexaple.com/js/jalerts/jquery.js?_=1464945951342

Can you help me please and show me what is wrong? thanks !

Comment: If I understood correctly, you want when user enters this URL in address bar: `http://www.example.com/products/something-nice` to actually show him this page: `http://www.example.com/products/index.php?product=something-nice`?

Comment: No mate, I want when user visits this url http://www.example.com/products/something-nice the server to load file index.php from root/products folder.. looks simple but doesn't happen. And user must stay on http://www.example.com/products/something-nice , not to be redirected..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside `/products/.htaccess` you can use these rules:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /products/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ index.php?product=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^[^/]+/([^/]+)/?$ index.php?product=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Working as a charm :) Thank you mate !

Comment: anubhava, I changed it to :
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /products/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/?$ index.php?product=$1 [L,QSA]

because instead of 1 dynamic folder after /products I will have 2 dynamic folders like products/aaaaa/bbbb

may I ask why the directives above stops index.php file to header user to error page if bbbb is not entered. How to change the code so to make it working? Thanks

Comment: and also the script above doesnt allow cyrilic urls.. how this can be fixed also, thanks

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you are asking about actual internal URL..
Url structure is root/products/dinamicfolder1/dinamicfolder2 - is this what you are asking mate? t should load index.php even if dinamicfolder2 is not entered

Comment: for example if user visits root/products/dinamicfolder1 - index.php from products folder should be loaded.. Now it doesn't load